# I want to recursively insert two lines in all files of my directory where it was not present?

Tags: unix, sed

I have a directory customer. I have many customers in customer directory. 
Now I want to add two lines in some process_config file within customer directory where it was not available.

For example:

```
/home/sam/customer/a1/na/process_config.txt
/home/sam/customer/p1/emea/process_config.txt
```

and so so.

Is this possible by single command like `find` & `sed`?

Comment: Where do you want to insert the 2 lines in the files? Just append to them?

Answer (score 0):

With a simple `for` loop :

```
for file in /home/sam/customer/*/*/process_config.txt; do
    printf "one line\nanother line\n" >> "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/sam/customer -name 'process_config.txt' -exec DoYourAddWithSedAwkEchoOrWhatever {} \;
```

- find give you the possibility to select each wanted (selected) file
- option `-exec` start a subshell with your command on this file.
- `{}` is the file name (full name) in this case.
- Use `\;` as end of command for the iteration (other command couldbe used with the standard behaviour of `;` ex `-exec echo 'line1' >> {} ; echo "line2" >> {} \;`

sed, awk or echo like in sample can modify the file

Comment: can you explain me how can I insert two lines with it?

Comment: `find /home/sam/customer -name 'process_config.txt' -exec echo "This is line1   \n    This is line 2" >> {} \;`

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: `-exec echo line >> {} \;` would not work because the shell would consume `>>`.

Comment: right, i test and can only solve by putting the command in a external file that is called by the line (my previous test). Also try using a xargs with same kind of problem. Event a sub shell using `{}`or `()` failed. Sorry, not a one liner solution using echo. I'll try with a sed ...

Comment: try this `find /home/sam/customer -name 'process_config.txt' -exec sed -i '$ a\^JThis is line1 \^J This is line 2' {} \;` where `^J` is a real new line